# Assert FormData in multipart/form-data request in Playwright

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, playwright, form-data

I try to test my POST `multipart/form-data` request using Playwright. I wait for the request to be made, get `postData()` and try to assert with FormData.

```
  const requestPromise = page.waitForRequest('**/endpoint')
  await helpers.clickButtonByName('Submit')

  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('test', 'something')
  expect((await requestPromise).postData()).toEqual(formData)
```

I get the error, like:

```
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: {Symbol(state): [{"name": "test", "value": "something"}]}
Received: "------WebKitFormBoundaryQWipcI3dAh3FVlJW·
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"test\"···
something·
------WebKitFormBoundaryQWipcI3dAh3FVlJW--·
"
```

I want to test that I send a valid payload in the request. How could I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playwright is not parsing `multipart/form-data` posts (it does parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). I think the most productive way is to perform a contains. Something like this:

```
const postData = (await requestPromise).postData();
for (const key in yourFormDataAsAnObject) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    expect(postData).toContain(`${key}="${obj[key]}"`);
  }
}
```

I bet you're expecting a better answer, but this is what I can think of.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great answer! I will use that idea